# How would you iterate through a list in retrolambda?

Tags: java, android, retrolambda

I have the following code

```
List<Trailer> trailers = response.body().getResults();
trailers.stream().forEach(trailer -> {
    View reviewView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.trailer_list_item, null);
    ((TextView) reviewView.findViewById(R.id.movies_trailers_list)).setText(trailer.getName());
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.movie_trailers);
    linearLayout.addView(reviewView);
});
```

Is there a way to get this same code to work with retrolambda? 
I need to iterate throught list results I get back and add it a view.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235441/use-rxjava-and-retrofit-to-iterate-through-list-and-augment-results-based-on-sub

Comment: Thanks for the help! Looking over it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd kindly suggest to use [streamsupport](https://github.com/stefan-zobel/streamsupport) as an additional library for the Java 8 streams part:

```
import java8.util.stream.StreamSupport;

StreamSupport.stream(trailers).forEach(trailer -> {
    View reviewView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.trailer_list_item, null);
    ((TextView) reviewView.findViewById(R.id.movies_trailers_list)).setText(trailer.getName());
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.movie_trailers);
    linearLayout.addView(reviewView);
});
```

The required changes for Java 8 stream code are usually quite small and (in most cases) mechanic.

It has extra appeal in that it also already provides the new Java 9 Stream methods [takeWhile](http://static.javadoc.io/net.sourceforge.streamsupport/streamsupport/1.5.2/java8/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java8.util.function.Predicate-) / [dropWhile](http://static.javadoc.io/net.sourceforge.streamsupport/streamsupport/1.5.2/java8/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile-java8.util.function.Predicate-) and all other Java 9 enhancements (especially in Optional and Collectors) and optimizations. You can find the API doc [here](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/net.sourceforge.streamsupport/streamsupport/1.5.2).